# Check whether a path is absolute or relative

Tags: c, linux, path

How do you check whether a path is absolute or relative, using C on Linux?

Comment: What exactly are you doing that you need to know?

Comment: Handling `#include "..."` directives, in particular checking whether the .c file's directory needs to be prepended to the given path.

Comment: Actually, you should be careful for this particular use case. Both the `<>` and `""` variants of `#include` in the C standard have an implementation-defined way of searching for header files, not necessarily what you think.

Comment: The standard says `""` should try something implementation defined before trying the `<>` path. In the case of both GCC and the Microsoft compiler, that something is trying either the given absolute path, or given path relative to the including file's directory. What else did you have in mind?

Comment: Oh. You want to inspect the source code and make sure you have it right for the include path? Your question implies wanting to write code that performs the detection, which is quite different. :)

Comment: @rwallace: The standard also states that `<>` is implementation defined. In C99, `<>` is implementation defined as per 6.10.2/2 and `""` as per 6.10.2/3. In other words, they're _both_ implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On Unix like systems (incl. Linux, macOS)**

If it starts with a slash it's absolute, otherwise it's relative.
That is because everything is part of a single tree starting at the root (`/`) and file systems are mounted somewhere in this tree.

**On Windows**

Windows uses backslashes (though slashes are also supported these days) and drive letters. But it's bit more complex:

- A path starting with a drive letter followed by a colon not followed by a backslash (or slash) can be relative to that drive's current directory.
- A path starting with a backslash (or slash) is absolute but on the current drive, so in that sense it is in fact relative (to the top of the current drive).
- A path starting with 2 backslashes is an UNC path (pointing to a network location) which is always absolute, except when the path starts with `\\?\` which is a special case to support longer paths.

So on Windows it's best to use the `PathIsRelative()` ([PathIsRelativeA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathisrelativea)/[PathIsRelativeW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathisrelativew)) function to determine if the path is relative or not.

Answer (score 18):

Absolute paths tend to start with the `/` character. Anything else is pretty much relative from the working directory.

Even directories with `..` sequences in them are considered absolute if they start with `/` since they end up at the same position in the file system (unless you change links and things but that's beyond the discussion of absolute and relative).

Answer (score 9):

It's absolute if it begins with a `/`, otherwise relative.

Answer (score 4):

Check if the path starts with `/` or not. if path starts with `/` you can assume it is absolute.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the path starts with / or not. if path starts with / you can assume it is absolute otherwise it's relative means it will update from pwd(present working directory)
But in Absolute case path will update relative to root directory